# Laravel 5.2 routes work only on root directory

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp, laravel-5

I can't access to my routes (404) when Laravel is installed in a folder not root domain.

For example if I install Laravel in root domain and add route `anyroutes` I can access to `localhost/anyroutes` with no problem.

BUT

If I install Laravel in a folder like `localhost/project/` and add that route: `localhost/project/public/anyroutes` it gives me 404. I have to mention that `localhost/project/public/index.php/anyroutes` WILL work.

I didn't have this problem in earlier versions of Laravel.

How can I fix this?

Apache (XAMPP), PHP 7, `mod_rewrite` enabled and ...

### Update:

`.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

apache conf:

```
<Directory />
    Allowoverride All
   # AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "E:/projects"
<Directory "E:/projects">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: did you check that your directory has a correct permission ?

Comment: @imrealashu Yeah it's okay. Do you have this problem or it's only me?

Comment: ya I had it but i changed the permission level and it worked. which os you are using ? windows, unix or linux ?

Comment: @imrealashu Windows. In windows we don't usually have permission issues ..

Comment: ya thats correct. are you sure you've done `composer update` or `composer install` after installation ?

Comment: @imrealashu Yeah I did that. But it didn't work. It's so strange.

Comment: Can you show up your .htaccess from your /public folder ? And your apache conf

Comment: @Soywod Yeah. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: This `.htaccess` is for earlier versions of Laravel. Not 5.2. I tried it. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I've tried all, never faced anything like this but once just because of permission issue nothing else.